# Proof of weakly representability for the summation of two representable functions

Tags: logic

I'm gonna prove that the addition of two representable functions is weakly representable.

Let's $\alpha(x,y)$ and $\beta(x,y)$ represents $y = f(x)$ and $y = g(x)$, respectively. My problem is that I'm not sure about the formula which represents $(f+g)(x)$. I've assumed that it is $\alpha(x,y) \vee \beta(x,y)$.

$f$ is representable. So,

If $y = f(x)$ then $N \vdash \alpha(x,y)$

If $y \neq f(x)$ then $N \vdash \neg \alpha(x,y)$

$g$ is representable. So,

If $y = g(x)$ then $N \vdash \beta(x,y)$

If $y \neq g(x)$ then $N \vdash \neg\beta(x,y)$

**To prove that $f+g$ is weakly-representable, is it sufficient to prove below?**

If $y = (f+g)(x)$ then $N \vdash (\alpha(x,y) \vee \beta(x,y))$

If $y \neq (f+g)(x)$ then $N \vdash \neg(\alpha(x,y) \vee \beta(x,y))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Your assumption about the formula representing $(f+g)(x)$ is wrong. You can consider something like:

$(\exists a)(\exists b)(\alpha(\bar{x},a) \wedge\beta(\bar{y},b) \wedge \bar{y} = a+b)$,

where $(f+g)(x) = y$